# undefined method `%' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error (`undefined method '%' for false:FalseClass`) is referencing this line

```
   rect = Rect.new(icon_index % 16 * 24, icon_index / 16 * 24, 24, 24)
```

Why is it producing this error? It was a part of some default code in the editing program, and I didn't run into this problem until recently.

Comment: What is `icon_index` this error tell you that you want to use `#%` method on the boolean object, so to make your question clearer, please add what is icon_index equal to(simple example), or where do you get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for instance you initialize `a` as `nil` and then you want to perform an operation using this value you'll see an `undefined method '%' for nil:NilClass` error, to avoid this you can check before if the value is `nil` in order to perform such operation with normality, maybe as:

```
puts (a % 1) if !a.nil?
```

This won't show you nothing, because as `a` is `nil`, it responds with `true` to your `if` statement.

The same could happen with a value initialized as `false`, if in this case `a` were `false` you wouldn't be able to perform an `%` operation using this object, because `%` would be waiting an `integer` value to the left:

```
a = false
puts (a % 1)
# => undefined method `%' for false:FalseClass (NoMethodError)
```

A possible solution, as before, could be to check if the value isn't `false`:

```
puts (a % 1) if a != false
```

You also could use `if a`, which could means something like if the value isn't `nil` and/or not `false`:

```
puts a % 1 if a
```

Or directly to validate if the value is an `integer` and is of `Fixnum` or `Numeric` class:

```
a = 1
puts a % 1 if a.class == Fixnum
# => 0
puts a % 1 if a.is_a? Fixnum
# => 0
puts a % 1 if a.is_a? Numeric
# => 0
```

In your case, you could do:

```
if icon_index
  rect = Rect.new(icon_index % 16 * 24, icon_index / 16 * 24, 24, 24)
end
```

Comment: Nicely explained.