# Rails paperclip error undefined method `before' for false:FalseClass when attaching image to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a model named Question that I want to attach a file to (diagram) using Paperclip (5.0.0). When the model is saved I get this error:

```
undefined method `before' for false:FalseClass
```

My Model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
  belongs_to :category

  has_attached_file :diagram
  validates_attachment_content_type :diagram, :content_type => ["image/jpg", 
    "image/jpeg", "image/png"], if: :hasdiagram

end
```

My Controller and the line the error occurs on

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @question = Question.new
    render :new
  end


  def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)  #ERROR OCCURS HERE
    if @question.save
      flash[:success] = "New question created"
      redirect_to admin_portal_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

 private

   def question_params
     params.require(:question).permit(:question, :option1, :option2, 
     :option3, :option4, :answer, :category_id, :subject_id, :diagram)
   end

end
```

Whole error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `before' for false:FalseClass):
app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

My form:

```
<h1 align="center">Add a new question</h1>
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
    <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @question %>
    <%= form_for @question, :url => { :controller => 'questions', :action => 'create'}, method: :post do |f| %>

      <div class="form-group" id="diagram-input">
        <%= f.file_field :diagram %>
      </div>

      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success btn-block" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Entire log:

```
Started POST "/admin/add_question" for 10.240.1.4 at 2017-11-12 15:39:10 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.240.1.4! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by QuestionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AFcHCrw6Dthasdesh5DNgdsxmFICxxPznyXtPDtxnp8zokpyZSeRHqiGC+K4SBMHehxYBgUXra30KTCj/AxUg==", "question"=>{"subject_id"=>"39", "category_id"=>"1", "hasdiagram"=>"1", "diagram"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8064f72100 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20171112-8403-ewq7ng.png>, @original_filename="187c38aa17afdc65ba5c1c5239219686.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"question[diagram]\"; filename=\"187c38aa17afdc65ba5c1c5239219686.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "question"=>"a", "option1"=>"a", "option2"=>"a", "option3"=>"a", "option4"=>"a"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/c5769bbf6ba9051718d946344886703720171112-8403-1v5gz0n.png'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `before' for false:FalseClass):
  app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:11:in `create'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (27.9ms)
```

Comment: @spickermann I added the whole error and the form from where I'm submitting

Comment: @spickermann yes it is line 12 I removed the show action

Comment: @spickermann Ok I added the server log for when the form is submitted

Comment: Not sure if it is a typo in SO but you are missing an ‘end’ for your if/else statement in your create method.

Comment: @ScottMonceaux sadly just a typo

Comment: So here is what I got so far..explanation of error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44099729/8503822 and the only thing I can think of as ‘before’ is your validation for content type. Something is returning false and running that into the validation which would give you this error.

Comment: @ScottMonceaux This fixed it! There was an extra bit of validation I forgot to copy and paste here which was causing the error. Thanks

Comment: @RT5754 no problem.

Comment: Did you include all validations into the question? Or did you remove parts from the `Question` model?

Comment: @spickermann yes there was an if statement after the validation that I mistakenly didn't copy. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Would you mind to update your question with the part that was causing the error and why it was causing that error? That would help others in the future if they have similar error messages. Otherwise, I advise to closing this question because it has no benefit for others

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the form is missing a `multipart: true` that is needed when uploading files. Change the `form_tag` like this:

```
<%= form_for @question, 
             url: { controller: 'questions', action: 'create'}, 
             method: :post,
             multipart: true do |f| %>
```

Read more about [uploading files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) in the Rails guides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added multipart: true to the form but it doesn't remove the error. Is there anything else I'm doing wrong?